# KerberosAuthException: LoginException: Java.lang.NullPointerException: invalid null input: name Error from Spark App

Tags: apache-spark, openshift, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to create CI CD pipeline for my spark application which connects to existing Hadoop cluster, read a table and then display it. I will be deploying my image using OpenShift.

My CI CD Structure:

CI repo

***/src/my_pyspark.py:***

1. Create SparkSession instance using SparkSession.builder.appName('TableReader').enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
2. set other spark conf
3. spark.sql("select * from my_table")
4. display using df.show()

***/conf/*/***

- all configuration related files like core-stat.xml, hive-env.sh, yarn-site.xml etc

My root directory has docker file which has openjdk base image and then install python and pre downloaded spark . spark-submit is called from this file.

When this code is deployed, image from openshift throws Error from *SparkSession* line:

```
An error occured while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext. : org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosAuthException: Failure to login: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Java.lang.NullPointerException: invalid null input: name
```

For security purpose, I can not share the files. Please let me know if I need to explain more on anything. Could anyone please explain why I am getting this error from the above details?